# Build error For Web Application in VS2008 when Intellisense Works

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build, intellisense, dll

When building the solution, the code behind is not picking up changes made to the applicaitons dlls. Intellisense works, and the page builds when using the "Build Page" command, however when trying to build the entire solution the build fails. Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much angst, it turns out the problem was the class in the business tier had the same name as the aspx file. Once the class was renamed, everything worked correclty.